# Disable the --more-- prompt in Cisco CLI

Tags: cisco

**show startup-config**:

```
!
line con 0
login local
length 0
line vty 0
exec-timeout 0 0
login local
length 0
line vty 1 4
login local
length 0
line vty 5 15
login local
length 0
!
```

However I still get prompted with the --more-- on long outputs.

Is there a setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Doing a `terminal length 0` (not in configure mode) does the trick.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to do this every time I connect to the switch.